# Nginx does not show custom root folder's files

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, default

I am using a classic load balancer in front of an nginx EC2 instance and have pointed the A-record of my site to the load balancer. I am getting the default nginx page even though my root is pointed to a custom folder /home/ubuntu/mydomain/pulic.

When I change the index.html file's contents under the html folder, I am able to see the changes. But, I don't know from where this page is pointed from. I have tried modifying the root path at /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf and /usr/src/nginx-1.13.6/conf/nginx.conf. But does not work(no change is seen).

Can anyone help me with this? Googled this in different ways and found no help.

All I am looking for is a secure HTTPS connection between the load balancer and the EC2 instance.

NOTE: I installed nginx manually and not using apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the command `nginx -t` it should output the location of the config file thats in use:

```
root@myhost:~# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

If you view that file you will find the main `http` config - the global config for the server. You may find the default site configured in this file, or it may be referenced by an include statement in another file such as `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`

I would suggest not editing the default site, and instead add an additional `server` block either within the main `http` section of your nginx.conf, or better in a seperate .conf file that is included into the main config file like this: `include /path/to/my/example.com.conf`. Doing this means accessing your server's IP via a browser will not show your website (you should replace the default document with a blank file).

If you wanted to host https://www.example.com you would create a config file such as /path/to/www.example.com.conf which contains:

```
# main https://www.example.com config
server {
  server_name www.example.com;
  listen 443 ssl;

  #public and private keys for your ssl certificate. 
  ssl_certificate /path/to/www.example.com/ssl/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/www.example.com/ssl/privkey.pem;
  # there are common sense values for SSL
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  server_tokens off;

  # you can generate this file from the shell:  openssl dhparam -out /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem 2048
  #ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;

  # if its just ELB you can restrict this to just TLSv1.2
  #ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

  # The following list should work and only use more modern ciphers, but do your research/trial and error
  # on which ciphers your ELB can use and pick the strongest.
  ##ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';


  #Adding this header will force browsers to only ever request HTTPS from your site.
  ##add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";


  #set your web root here:
  root /path/to/www.example.com/httpdocs;

  #default document
  index index.html;

}

# redirect HTTP www.example.com to HTTPS for cannonical URL
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Then in the main nginx.conf file, inside the `http` section add the line:

```
include /path/to/www.example.com.conf;
```

Run `nginx -t` again to check your changes are valid, then test in a browser.